# Extract values from map with stream

Tags: java, dictionary, filter

Assume that I have this map :

```
String str = ResourceUtils.getResourceAsString("/myjson.json");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

TypeReference rootType = new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
            };
List<Map<String, Object>> root = mapper.readValue(str, rootType);
Map<String, Object> map = root.stream().reduce(new LinkedHashMap<>(), (dest, m2) -> {
        dest.put(m2.get("map").toString(), m2.get("values"));
        return dest;
});
```

Where str is a json file that contains "map" and "values" fields, map is a string and values is an array of string.

How can I retrieve a list (or array) of Strings that contains values of filtered keys?
I am at this point for the moment :

```
List<String> startWords = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("x") || x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

I know that there will be a .collect(Collectors::toList()) at the end, but if I try a flatMap after my filter, I have an Stream inferred error.

Thanks!

EDIT: The output intended is a list like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.put("hello");
list.put("world");
```

Comment: What are you trying to put into your `startWords` list?

Comment: I want to put all values of filtered keys

Comment: Is the value of your input Map an Object or a String?

Comment: Since you want a List<String> as result, is it the keys that should be returned? Otherwise, how should Object be cast to String?

Comment: I must have forgot something in my explainations. I updated my post, hope it makes it clearer!

Comment: If the value of `map` is an Object, how do you obtain from it the String that you want in your output List?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `flatMap` but simply `map`. It should look like this:

```
List<String> startWords = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("x") || x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                .map(x -> x.getValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You use `flatMap` when you want to "flatten" some data structure. For example if you can a List of Lists then you will use `flatMap` to get a single stream of all elements.

Comment: okay I got it! I just have one more error, it says that Collector<Object, Object, List<String>> is not a functional interface. Do you have any idea why ? Thank you for your help!

Comment: There should be `collect(Collectors.toList())` instead, my bad. Editted my answer, should work now.

Comment: I didn't saw your answer, but now that works great! Thank you very much.

Comment: @faceID accept the answer that works for you so it is easier to find for other people later on.

Comment: Okay i'll do it, thanks. It is working but maybe not as I expected, I now have a list where index 0 is an array list with one word in each, index 1 same etc... Is it possible to have a list of words ? like List<String> msg= Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!", "How", "Are", "You");

Comment: @faceID No, not so long you declare your map to be Map<String, Object>. It feels like this is all the wrong approach for decoding your json message.

Answer (score 0):

you must add a map before collect, like this :

```
List<Object> startWords = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("x") || x.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        .map(x -> x.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and the map depend to what you need : getKey or getValue

Comment: Thanks for you help ! I have another error now, I replied on comment above :)

Comment: change the type of startsWords to List<Object> because the map contains object as value